# Switch pyflakes linter from python2 to python3 in ALE

Tags: plugin-ale

pyflakes (with ALE) automatically defaults to python2 instead of python3 and gives me false errors and there are no variables in ALE documentation letting me change python versions. Thanks for any help in advance.

P.S I just switched to MyPy linter, it defaults to python3

P.S (2) Got it! Add `let g:ale_python_pyflakes_executable = 'pyflakes3'` to your .vimrc

Comment: You may need to check your installation of pyflakes. Is it installed with `python3 -m pip`

Comment: Yeah, I installed it as `apt install pyflakes` first and then did both `pip3 install pyflakes` and `pip2 install pyflakes` to make sure

Comment: But... `pip2` is python2... and check the pyflakes in your path

Comment: paths...paths..of course, turns out there is a separate pyflakes executable for python3, that is called pyflakes3 so to get python3 syntax support I had to add `'let g:ale_python_pyflakes_executable = 'pyflakes3'` to .vimrc. Amen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add let `g:ale_python_pyflakes_executable = 'pyflakes3'` to your .vimrc and be at peace